# Merge uniqMerge Values in Clickhouse

Tags: clickhouse

I have two records in schema `tags`,

```
CREATE TABLE default.tags
(
    `tag_id` String,
    `count` SimpleAggregateFunction(sum, Int64),
    `users` AggregateFunction(uniq, String),
    `sessions` AggregateFunction(uniq, String)
)
```

[image]

And i want to merge all users into one record. I've tried `uniqState(users)` but it gives me something with type `AggregateFunction(uniq, AggregateFunction(uniq, String))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use uniqMerge function  `uniqMerge(users)`
https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/aggregate-functions/combinators/#aggregate_functions_combinators-merge

https://kb.altinity.com/altinity-kb-queries-and-syntax/state-and-merge-combinators

Comment: I don't want to have the count of unique users. I want to merge them into one record as a new AggregateFunction value.

Comment: uniqMergeState(users) https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/aggregate-functions/combinators/#aggregate_functions_combinators-mergestate

Comment: another option you can use plus (+) operator